# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'courses' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem since I tried to use get_absolute_url(self): to enter in a url beyond a photo.
When I used , my index.html stopped running.

Here I have the top level url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from simplemooc.core import views, urls
from simplemooc.courses import views, urls
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               path('', include(('simplemooc.core.urls', 'simplemooc'), namespace='core')),
               path('cursos', include(('simplemooc.courses.urls', 'simplemooc'), namespace='courses'))]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here courses/url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from simplemooc.courses import views

urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index'),
                   path('/<slug:slug>/', views.details, name='datails')]
```

Here courses/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class CourseManager(models.Manager):

    def search(self, query):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            models.Q(name__icontains=query) | \
            models.Q(description__icontains=query)
        )


class Course(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')
    description = models.TextField('Descrição Simples', blank=True)
    about = models.TextField('Sobre o Curso', blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(
        'Data de Início', null=True, blank=True
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='courses/images', verbose_name='Imagem',
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        'Criado em', auto_now_add=True
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Atualizado em', auto_now=True)

    objects = CourseManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:datails', (), {'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Curso'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cursos'
        ordering = ['name']
```

And here courses/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Course

def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    template_name = 'courses\index.html'
    context = {
        'courses': courses
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def details(request, slug):
   course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
   context = {
       'course': course
   }
   template_name = 'courses/datails.html'
   return render(request, template_name, context)
```

My problem happens when I use:

```
<a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}">
```

in my index.html

Please, Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is your file named url.py or urls.py?

Comment: All my file names are urls.py. The top level is urls.py and low level is courses/urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

your output will be a list of the course instances, so you should iterate through the output and correct your get absolute method

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('courses:datails',, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: I change my "get absolute method" as you said to:

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('courses:datails',, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

But, when I use <a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}"> in my index.html still stop running.

Do you know how can I iterate my course instances output? I just want use the "slug"

https://github.com/bqgama/first-django-project

Thank you for try to help me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for try to help me.

I managed do what I wanted. I did this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '%s' % self.slug
```

I don't know why is not running with reverse function.

Thank you!!